# Rendering template dynamically in Rails ViewComponent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, view-components

I have a SectionComponent Class as follow :

```
class SectionComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  def initialize(..)
    ...
  end 
end
```

And a matching `section_component.html.erb` file.
It works perfectly fine.

Though I want to render a different template depending on a keyworded argument in the intialize method. And I can't figure out how to render a different template.

I have tried to explicitly render a different template (without playing with the intialize method yet):

```
def render    
  render_template(:section_details_component, template_path: "section_details_component.html.erb")
end
```

But each time my server complains it can't find the template. Actually the render block seems to never be hit.
Is there a specific syntax to adding a different template ?
Or maybe a workaround ?

Otherwise I will write as many components as I have templates...

Comment: Check the variant context: https://viewcomponent.org/api.html#with_variantvariant and define the "details" as a variant template: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-variants-option

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ViewCompoennt is not designed to handle different templates for the same component.

My solution is to have a content method that loads an .erb file dynamically:

```
def content
  renderer = ERB.new(@file_content)
  renderer.result(binding)
end
```

file path being declared in the `initialize` method this way :

```
file_path = "app/components/section_component/#{section_name}.html.erb"
@file_content = File.read(file_path)
```

And my viewComponent view is made of a single line of code :

```
<%= content.html_safe %>
```

This is obviously a edge case for a viewcompoennt. I have used a compoennt here instead of using a partial in order to separate logic, and because I have several degrees of nested partials for which locals forwarding is not trivial.
ViewCompoennt solves these issues..